# Ajax PrimeFaces not to render the event or disable checkbox

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

In doc it doesn't have a property render and i did a smoke test by having other components wrapping around `p:ajax` (Exception: but event attribute is unavailable) am i missing something here?

```
<p:ajax event="rowSelectCheckbox" listerner="somemethod()" update="someId"/>
```

Comment: Do you mean selectBooleanCheckbox?

Comment: yes selectBooleanCheckbox event="rowSelectCheckbox" this fires an exception as unavialable

Comment: i did added selectCheckbox, outputlink is there other component tag i should be used with p:ajax

Answer (score 1):

Just omit the `event` totally:

```
<p:ajax listener="..." update="..."/>
```

It defaults to `event="valueChange"` and `process="@this"`, which is often what one want.

If it does'nt work as expected check the [Primefaces user guide](http://www.primefaces.org/documentation), find your component and look for "Ajax behavior events" or look for attributes beginning with "on...".

About `h:outputLink`: its not a Primefaces tag so it should have been `f:ajax` for this one. However it does'nt work because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737759/how-to-ajax-jsf-2-outputlink).

Read more in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13221089/primefaces-selectoneradio-ajax) answer.

Comment: Okay.. let me try above

Answer (score 1):

rowSelectCheckbox will be use with SelectEvent.

xhtml

```
<p:ajax event="rowSelectCheckbox" listerner="#{bean.selectCheckbox}" update="someId"/>
```

managedbean

```
public void selectCheckbox(SelectEvent event){

}
```